# Как написать свой анализатор типа/класса?

Tags: c++

Добрый вечер. Хотел узнать как написать свой анализатор типа (нужно для моего класса динамического массива на отлов ошибок).
Сначала подумал про typeOf, sizeOf. Но есть маленькая проблема. Мой динамический массив может использовать например класс больших чисел или каких-либо геом.структур. Какие могут быть выходы ?

Пример проблемы :

```
Dynamic_Array <BigInt> a(10);
double b = 1.25;
a.add(b); //здесь в массив a добавляется элемент b = 1.25 , однако в параметризации 
          //данного массива указан класс BigInt, хотелось бы, чтобы программа 
          //выводила ошибку на этапе выполнения программы , то есть код
          //написанный до этого выполнялся, но после попытки добавить элемент в массив
          //программа выкидывала exception
```

Пример реализации (BigInt, Dynamic_Array) :

```
class BigInt {
    private : 
    int len;
    int a[10000];
    public : 
    BigInt();
    BigInt(string s);
};
template <class T>
class Dynamic_Array {
    private : 
    int size;
    int capacity;
    T *array;
    public :
    void add(T value);
};
```

Comment: Вы хотите, чтобы приведённый код был валиден или, наоборот, не валиден и выдавал ошибку компиляции?

Comment: @alexolut чтобы отлавливал ошибку и выдавал её.

Comment: В таком случае достаточно отсутствия неявного преобразования из `double` в `BigInt`, а если у `BigInt` есть конструктор с типом `double`, то можно сделать его `explicit`. В общем, приведите минильную реализацию `BigInt` для начала, но лучше и `Dynamic_Array` тоже. Посмотрите как стоит оформить [mcve].

Comment: У Вас код не валидный, ну и для минимальной реализации потроха функции `add` не нужны. Достаточно объявления. Если `Dynamic_Array` параметризован типом `BigInt`, то при отсутствии неявного преобразования `double` → `BigInt`, вызов `add(1.25)` и так должен давать ошибку компиляции. Вы точно почитали, что такое [mcve]?

Comment: @alexolut согласен, внутренность *add* не нужно. Да, компилятор выдает ошибку. Однако я думал над тем, как давать программе компилироваться , но при выполнении её она бы показывала ошибку (например "Error type"). Думал использовать try-catch , но не знаю как четко обрабатывать тот факт, что тип добавленного значения отличается от типа моего массива.

Comment: Так а зачем переносить проверку со стадии компиляции на стадию выполнения, если код всё равно будет требовать правки в случае ошибки?

Comment: Мне это скорее надо для просто проверки ошибок. Из разряда : нам надо создать массив точек , и вдруг кто-то решил добавить в этот массив число , а не точку. Тогда программа должна говорить, что данное действие незаконно и выдавать ошибку.

Comment: Для этого надо, чтобы `Dynamic_Array` мог в принципе одновременно хранить разные типы. Т.е. чтобы ловить ошибку при выполнении, надо иметь уже скомпилированную программу. А у Вас такой нет.

Comment: @alexolut почему? Я вполне могу написать Dynamic_Array<int> a(1) и в той же программе Dynamic_Array<double> b(1);
Произвести некоторые (законные) операции и не программа скомпилируется и даже будет работать.

Comment: Потому что существуют неявные преобразования между стандартными `int` и `double`, и обычно это никому не мешает. В Вашем первом примере другие типы и преобразования `double` → `BigInt` нет. Соответственно нет и собранной программы с упомянутым кодом. Вы всё же подумайте и постарайтесь описать проблему чётче в вопросе. Пока что какая-то путаница наблюдается.

Comment: @alexolut я добавил изменения

Comment: С шаблонами путаница какая-то. Код копировали или по памяти писали?

Comment: @alexolut из своего кода. Почему путаница ?

Comment: Потому что шаблонный `Dynamic_Array` должен быть, а не `BigInt`, ну и точек с запятой не хватает. Нельзя взять код из вопроса и использовать его для компиляции.

Comment: @alexolut простите, понял ошибку, исправил!

Comment: @alexolut просто они у меня в разных файлах.

Comment: В `BigInt` конструкторы какие? `private` части в вопросе не нужны, они на проблему не влияют.

Comment: @alexolut пустой и со string.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66338/discussion-between-alexolut-and-openspace).

Answer (score 2):

Не совсем понятен вопрос что имено хочется, но возможно комбинация

- static_assert: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_assert
- type_traits: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/type_traits

поможет решить вашу проблему
Например:

```
template<class T>
class Array
{
public:
    Array();
    Array(const A& other)
    {
        static_assert(std::is_trivially_copyable<T>::value, "T must be is trivially copyable."
        // Такая проверка гарантирует что тип T можно просто копировать через 
        // memcpy. Например, struct X {int a; int b}; Но struct { std::string str}; 
        // уже не пройдет проверку
        buffer = new T[other.size];
        size = other.size;
        std::memcpy(buffer, other.buffer);
    }
    template<class V>
    void add(const V v) 
    {
         std::static_assert(std::is_same<T, V>::value, "Compilation ERROR");
         // тут добавляй
    }
private:
    T* buffer;
    size_t size;
}
```

Comment: Имелось в виду. Вдруг я создам массив BigInt , а потом захочу добавить в него double или char , хотелось чтобы он исключал данную ошибку.

Comment: @openspace А можете пример псевдокода использования написать, а то не понятно что именно вы хотите

Comment: добавил пример.

Comment: На месте BigInt может быть любой другой класс написанный мною , просто нужно как-то понять , что при добавлении я пытаюсь добавить другой класс или тип.

Comment: @openspace Добавил add, но не понятно зачем тебе эта проверка, если BigInt нормально конструируется из int, то пусть добавляется. Если не хочешь, то добавь explicit к конструктору от int